# How to prevent of using environment variables with templates?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, mustache

I have a Spring Boot (2.1.4.RELEASE) web application with Mustache templates. Everything is ok, but I've mentioned strange behavior: a placeholder with my custom name "**user.name**" has value different than I expected. Looks like Mustache takes it from the **system variable**.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I pass a domain object User form a controller to a template. The user has "name" property.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class MyController {
    @GetMapping
    ModelAndView get() {
        return new ModelAndView(
                    "my_view"
            Collections.singletonMap("user", new User())
        );
    }
}
```

This is my Mustache configuration:

```
@Component
public class MustacheConfig {
    @Bean
    public Mustache.Compiler mustacheCompiler(
        Mustache.TemplateLoader mustacheTemplateLoader,
        Environment environment
    ) {

        MustacheEnvironmentCollector collector = new MustacheEnvironmentCollector();

        collector.setEnvironment(environment);

        return Mustache.compiler()
            .defaultValue("")
            .withLoader(mustacheTemplateLoader)
            .withCollector(collector);

    }
}
```

I've tried to do some manipulations with the "environment" object, but it is immutable.

As an option, I can change the "user.name" name to something like "blablaUser.name", but I believe it is not a true way.

Comment: I guess, unless you modify the Mustache code, there is nothing else you can do. Apparently Mustache first check the `Collector` to resolve the property before checking the model. So rename your model attribute to something else as `user` will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using of **this** pointer:

```
{this.user.name}
```

it points explicitly the context of the variable.